# Why doesn't ts call the function when declaring a variable, indicating a type error

Tags: typescript

- [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmAjDAvDAFAQwE4HNEBcMA3gFAwUwDWApgJ5FgCuAtgEY3YA0pAvgJQoAfGUoxQkEABsaAOikhcWPIn59SpBInSjaDGIj5rSE6DAAmmKJlQlylPUUQ8xmJz16ak6S9eNadewpHAxdKN1CjIA)
- refrence:

```
const fn1 = (arg1: {
    key: number,
})=>{
    console.log(arg1)
}

fn1({
 key: 1
})

const data = {
    key: 1,
    a: 1,
}
fn1(data)

fn1({
    key: 1,
    a: 1,
})
```

- [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmAjDAvDAFAQwE4HNEBcMA3gFAwUwDWApgJ5FgCuAtgEY3YA0pAvgJQoAfGUoxQkEABsaAOikhcWPIn59SpBInSjaDGIj5rSE6DAAmmKJlQlylPUUQ8xmJz16ak6S9eNadewpHAxdKN1CjIA)
- who can give some help: Why doesn't ts call the function when declaring a variable, indicating a type error

Comment: Please see the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks)

Answer (score 0):

```
const fn1 = (arg1: {
    key: number,
})=>{
    console.log(arg1)
}
```

here you declare that the parameter should have a key named "key" and a value as a number, nothing more. if you want to create a type for a parameter that should expect any any key with a number value pair, you need to change it as

```
const fn1 = (arg1: {
    [k: string]: number
})=>{
    console.log(arg1)
}
```

Comment: hi, I want to show: the fn's param arg1,  but the variable: "data" is not satisfied with the type . I want to know: why not tip type error?

Answer (score 0):

### To solve the error

As the error message suggest:

```
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'a' does not exist in type '{ key: number; }'
```

It is the difference between object literal and a named object.

However, you can still make your function generic to make it compiles.

```
const fn1 = <T extends {key: number}>(arg1: T)=>{
    console.log(arg1)
}
```

### Edit

Maybe your question is why, but not how. It is acutally [a feature introduced in TypeScript 1.6](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) to catch programmer human errors on misspelling the property names.

You can turn on `suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors` in your tsconfig if you prefer to ignore it. But it is generally [not recommended](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#suppressExcessPropertyErrors) by typescript.